# Elasticsearch NEST - SortAsceding doesn't sorts documents

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to sort the result set based on a field name. But Sort doesn't works with **string** type.

Tried Code:-

```cs
public class Company
{
    public long Number { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

My problem is : Sorting is not done when I use SortAscending API, like below

```cs
var resultSet = client.Search<Article>(s => s
                            .Type("Company")
                            .From(0)
                            .Size(200)
                            .QueryString("Stack OverFlow")
                            .SortAscending(f => f.Name));
```

Note: Documents are listed as Sorted if I set field name as Number(f => f.Number)

Please help

Comment: Can you please provide example data stored in your index and the mapping you use?

Answer (score 4):

Your issue with sorting on the name field in your index is probably related to the fact that the field is being analyzed/tokenized. From the [Elasticsearch Sort Guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html):

> For string based types, the field sorted on should not be analyzed / tokenized.

Therefore, you need to provide an additional field that is not analyzed/tokenized to perform your sort against. You can accomplish this by adding an additional field to your documents and setting the mapping for that type/field to `not_analyzed` or you can leverage `multi_field` (now just `fields` in version 1.x) on your existing name field. Please refer to the following for guidance on how to accomplish either of these options:

- [Multi-Fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html) (or Fields in v1.X)
- [Mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html)